# How do I add extra functionality to the same onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick, bind

I have a

```
<input onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions........" id='input-no1'></input>
```

element and I want to add a second onclick event to it using jQuery

What I mean is that once the onclick event: `javascript:WebForm_DoP....` is executed I want the page to reload by calling `location.reload();`

How do I add this extra functionality to the same onclick attribute of the above element?

I had a look at bind(), but the syntax requires that I type in all events in sequence. What I want to do is add a subsequent event to the same onclick function, whatever the initial event maybe ( I might not even know what the initial event is..)

Thanks for your help in advance.

**EDIT:**

the code I am now using is:

```
$("#input-no1").bind('click',function()
{
   location.reload();
});
```

but nothing happens, even though the element is selected and I get no errors.. I also tried :

```
$("#input-no1").bind('onclick',function()
{
   location.reload();
});
```

but still nothing

Answer (score 1):

You could add both functions to your onclick handler directly.

```
<input onclick="WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions();location.reload(); " />
```

Or you could attach it separately using:

```
$("#input-no1").click(function () { 
    location.reload();
    //more code
});​
```

**Example**: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uM3j/)**

Comment: I want to do this using jQuery, not by retyping the whole element, but by simply selecting it based on an id that it has (I omitted that) and then adding the extra functionality to its onclick event

Comment: @NortonCommander updated answer. You can have multiple onclick-listeners reigstered this way.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm afraid this bind syntax adds nothing to the element, even though the element is selected correctly and I get no errors when running the code..

Comment: Yes I see that, but the exact same syntax is not working in my case. Maybe it has to do with the fact that the already existing event is of type "javascript:DoPostBack....." which is basically a js script that adds a new item to the basket..

Comment: Ahh... If your `doPostBack` is causing a server-postback in itself, the JS further won't execute, and hence won't hit the other handler. If you perform `location.reload` first, then the other function won't get executed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19401/discussion-between-cthulhu-and-norton-commander)